# Jquery ajax like for social network

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$('button[id="btnLike"]').on('click', function (e) {
            var userId = $("#logedUserId").val();
            var postId = $(this).data('id');
            if ($(this).toggleClass('btn btn-default')) {
                $(this).toggleClass('btn btn-info');
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("UpdatePostThumbsUp", "Main")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { 'userId': userId, 'postId': postId, 'flag': true },
                    cache: false
                });
            }
            else {
                $(this).toggleClass('btn btn-default');
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("UpdatePostThumbsUp", "Main")',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { 'userId': userId, 'postId': postId, 'flag': false },
                    cache: false
                });
            }
        });
```

I don't know why it has only worked with the if clause (the if clause is work success that mean method UpdatePostThumbsUp in controller (MVC) is work normally), but not with the else clause. 
Button like in html:

```
<button type="button" id="btnLike" class="btn btn-default" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 6px" data-id="@p.PostId">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> Like
                </button>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: why the else clause isn't work :(

Comment: Try to change `if($(this).toggleClass('btn btn-default'))`to `if($(this).hasClass('btn-default'))`

Comment: `toggleClass()` returns `jQuery`, which is always going to evaluate to true.  http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Answer (score 0):

This `$(this).toggleClass('btn btn-default')`, will always return a **jQuery**, that converted to `boolean` is **true**, so you will always go to the if branch.

Try using if `($(this).hasClass('btn btn-default'))`, should do the trick.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/